# Are terms tangential acceleration and normal acceleration only used for instantaneous velocity?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, differentiation, calculus

Are terms tangential acceleration and normal acceleration only used
for instantaneous velocity?

Answer (score 0):

These only exist for instantaneous velocity. A tangent to a path is a line where the slope of the line is the rate of change at that point, so yes it would apply for only instantaneous velocity. For normal acceleration the same thing applies.